# c++ symbol _ZNSsC2ERKSsjj

Tags: c++, symbols

My app crash at c++ symbol _ZNSsC2ERKSsjj.
I used c++filt to find the symbol as follow.

`# c++filt _ZNSsC2ERKSsjj`

`std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)`

What is this symbol mean?

Answer (score 2):

It is the constructor of `std::string` that takes a `const std::string&`, and two `unsigned int`s ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)):

```
basic_string( const basic_string& other, 
              size_type pos, 
              size_type count = std::basic_string::npos,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

<sup>*(Your implementation is, compliantly, replacing the optional parameter design with a pair of overloads, the one without the allocator parameter being the one you're seeing here.)*</sup>

**You are almost certainly going out of the bounds of the input string,** if it's even a valid string in the first place.

Comment: IIRC it's valid for implementations to replace that default argument with an overload pair.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes two positions (unsigned int). This constructs a substring of the argument.